# How to know the control flow during transition in state-machine?

Tags: c, debugging, kernel-module, state-machine, printk

***I've been studying*** spaghetti-based ***state-machine***, meaning that it's composed of a bunch of `if-else` statements scattered everywhere, ***in large kernel module*** recently ***in order to port this module to other platform***.

To understand how control flow goes between each state, I use `printk()` in the first place to print every line number so that I can see every detail of program behavior in run-time. However, too many `printk()` increase too much processing load and result in wrong behavior.

Afterward, I try `printk_once()` and `printk_ratelimited()` to reduce  line number. But this way causes another problem, especially at the time during transition.

Let me explain why:

Suppose there are four states `A`, `B`, `C`, and `D`, and each state's control flow is overlapped partly with each other. Also, there are two events `e1` and `e2` that I can trigger by plugging/unplugging hardware.

Furthermore, we define `stable state` as a state being stable, meaning that the path of control flow for this state is not changing until event occurs; We also define `unstable state` as a state  being unstable, meaning that this state is just a transition state for other states.

```
event    current state    next state

x              A              A   <---- always start from A
e1             A              B
x              B              C
e2             C              D
x              D              A

A, C: stable state
B, D: unstable state
```

If I use `printk_once()`, I'm not able to get all path of control flow from `A` to `C` as a whole, because some part of it are the same, and already be printed.

If I use `printk_ratelimited()`, it's not guaranteed to capture the path of control flow for transition from `A` to `C` because the span is too short to be captured.

***What I want is a control flow that clearly shows how program runs step by step*** from state `A` to `B` then to `C`, so that I can totally understand what's going on between each state.

That's it.

I would like to know how people deal with this. Thanks!

Comment: "meaning that this state is just a transition state for other states" What does that matter? Overall I don't really understand the question - you have a messy state machine, and...? Do you wish to rewrite it from scratch? Do you wish to salvage it?

Comment: @Lundin I refined the post, and it should be more understandable now. Please take a look.

Comment: Not sure how by just tracing **events** you want to collect information about **states**. If you find `printk` mechanism too time consumable (so you need to use `printk_once` or `printk_ratelimited` for omit some events), then you could try other mechanisms. E.g. you could look into tracepoints. Stack Overflow is a **bad place** for open-ended questions, when you ask for directions towards the "great" purpose.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thanks for mentioning tracepoints, I will look at it. BTW, what place do you suggest when asking open-ended questions?

Comment: I don't think that some of Stack Exchange site will accept open-ended questions like yours. In the current state your question requires a lot of **discussion** to be taken before one could understand your goal and could suggest a solution. But Question/Answer (QA) format implies none or very little discussion.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Could you please tell me which part is not clear enough at once so that I can try make it close to closed-ended question?

Comment: Actually, the only thing I get from your post is that you want to collect information about hitting many lines of code. E.g I don't understand how do you want to "understand what's going on between each state" by having this information. Well, if having information about **all hits**, then one probably could understand what is going on. But if you want to **reduce** that information, then it is unclear how much hits do you need for "understand".